# my Accordion Tabbed Pages going wrong

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i have a content and inside the content i want to put some settings of the user account, so they can change their information..

here is my code
CSS

```
   *{
    font-family:Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif}
body{
    background-color:#33CC33;
    font-size:0.7em;}
p{
    font-size:1em;
    margin:0 0 1em 0;
    text-align:justify}

dl{
    padding:10px;
    min-width:960px;}

dl dt{
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    border-radius:5px;
    border:1px solid #ccc;
    margin:0;
    width:400px;}

dl dt a{
    color:#000;
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:10px;
    display:block;
    }

dl dd{
    color:#ccc;
    margin:0;
    width:400px;
    overflow:hidden;
    -webkit-transition:height 1s ease;
    -moz-transition:height 1s ease;
    -o-transition:height 1s ease;}  

dl dd p{
    padding:10px;
    margin:0;}

dl dd:not(:target){
    height:0;}

dl dd:target{
    height:900px;}

dl a.ie:hover dd, dl a.ie:focus dd{
    height:auto;
    color:#ccc !important;}
```

HTML

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="tab.css">
<dl>
<dt><a href="#section1">Account Settings</a></dt>
<dd id="section1">
      <table>
      <form action="" method="post" name="register_form">

      <td><input type="text" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" size="50" /></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
      <td><input type="text" name="reemail" placeholder="Re-Enter Email" size="50" /></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
      <td><input type="password" name="password" placeholder="New Password" size="50" /></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
      <td>
      <input type="text" name="fullname" placeholder="Full Name" size="50" />
      </td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
      <td>
      <input type="text" name="birthday" placeholder="Day Birth YYYY-MM-DD" size="29" />
          <select id="gender" name="gender">
                <option value="Male">Male</option>
                <option value="Female">Female</option>
                <option value="Others">Others</option>                
          </select>
</dd>

<dt><a href="#section2">Privacy Settings</a></dt>
<dd id="section2">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</dd>

<dt><a href="#section3">What Settings</a></dt>
<dd id="section3">
Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
</dd>
</dl>
```

and this is my fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/obink/kNs8d/

What i see the problem is when i click on the section1 at the first time, everything is going okay, but when i change to the section2 weird things are coming...

and ow ya, i only took a CSS and HTML for it, i'm trying to make it work like jQuery or javascript("when you going to section1, the section1 will ease in and the other section ease out. Otherwise when you go to the section2, the other section will ease out and section2 will ease in")

I'm begging for help :( please...

sorry for my English.

Comment: 'tab.css' <--- what is this supposed to add? (Since the include of it need to have the correct url)

Comment: AND to add some value thats not really worth an answer.After poking at it for a couple of minutes, I suppose that when you select the contained sections it 'untransforms' it all, hence leaving you at square one. (But hey, I've never used transitions).

Comment: Open the fiddle that you have done and look at the HTML panel.  You will see that the first </tr> is red. That is because you didn't open the tr. Fix it, and it goes green. Some lines after that, a </dd> is also red. ... Are you closing your table ? Are yu closing your form ?

Comment: @luc tab.css mean that css page that i wrote, u can poke in the fiddle if u like.
this is my first time to use transitions, on the book that i bought told me about transition can ease like javascript do.

Comment: @vals oh god... my mistake.. wait i will check my code and update this question... thx val

Answer (score 0):

ohhh everything is all of my mistake

i forgotten to close the form and the table tag

```
  </form>
  </table>
```

and some of the  and  tag is not closed yet

lol
sorry to bother u